# ¿Can i add a call to action button on an amp website that leads to a NON amp survey?

Tags: amp-html

I want to make the amp version of my landing page, but i got a survey (which is my call to action) which is non amp, cause its a third party solution (typeform). I need my visitors to fill out the surveys (in marketing terms that means a convertion for us). So i want to know if i can put a regular call to action button on my amp (accelerated mobile page) that starts this non-amp survey. the user could answer the survey on a new tab. it does not have to be iframed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! AMP doesn't impose any such restrictions.